# Which model/technique to use for specific sentence extraction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have a dataset of tens of thousands of dialogues / conversations between a customer and customer support. These dialogues, which could be forum posts, or long-winded email conversations, have been hand-annotated to highlight the sentence containing the customers problem. For example:

> Dear agent, I am writing to you because I have a very annoying problem with my washing machine. I bought it three weeks ago and was very happy with it. However, this morning the door does not lock properly. Please help

> Dear customer.... etc

The highlighted sentence would be:

> However, this morning the door does not lock properly.

1. What approaches can I take to model this, so that in future I can automatically extract the customers problem? The domain of the datasets are broad, but within the hardware space, so it could be appliances, gadgets, machinery etc.
2. What is this type of problem called?
   I thought this might be called "intent recognition", but most guides seem to refer to multiclass classification. The sentence either is or isn't the customers problem. I considered analysing each sentence and performing binary classification, but I'd like to explore options that take into account the context of the rest of the conversation if possible.
3. What resources are available to research how to implement this in Python (using tensorflow or pytorch)

I found a [model on HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/TODBERT) which has been pre-trained with customer dialogues, and have read the research paper, so I was considering fine-tuning this as a starting point, but I only have experience with text (multiclass/multilabel) classification when it comes to transformers.

Comment: You can treat this as a span labeling problem. Look at what is called "token classification" in Huggingface Transformers.

Comment: Do you have any information on the average lengths (ideally in words/tokenized units) of your documents? I feel that solutions proposed so far do not really deal well with long inputs...

Comment: In one sample the average length of each post was 84 words, at a rough guess I'd say each dialogue has about 10 posts on average.

Comment: This question looks to me like it's ["asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If not, could you improve the wording so that it's more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a specific sentence (without any modification) from the original input text, that is often referred to as  'span classification'  where the output is the index of the first and last word of the specific sentence.
The state-of-the-art now is the attention models like BERT
.You can check the Bert models that are designed for the 'span classification' problem in huggingface as RobertaForQuestionAnswering https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/roberta#transformers.TFRobertaForQuestionAnswering that uses TensorFlow or PyTorch library.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem where you want to extract the customer problem from the original text is called **Extractive Summarization** and this type of task is solved by `Sequence2Sequence` models.

The main reason for this type of model being called `Sequence2Sequence` is because the input and the output of this model would both be text.

I recommend you to use a transformers model called [Pegasus](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/pegasus) which has been pre-trained to predict a masked text, but its main application is to be fine-tuned for text summarization (**extractive** or abstractive).

This Pegasus model is listed on [Transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) library, which provides you with a simple but powerful way of fine-tuning transformers with custom datasets. I think [this notebook](https://gist.github.com/jiahao87/50cec29725824da7ff6dd9314b53c4b3) will be extremely useful as guidance and for understanding how to fine-tune this Pegasus model.

Comment: I want to highlight that Pegasus is originally trained as an *abstractive* summarization model, which might introduce factual inconsistencies. I personally didn't find any information how this is guaranteed to be strictly extractive, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong here ;-)